# Filename with varing date and time for restore database

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime, filenames, restore

I am trying to pick up a daily .bak file which has a static name but a date and time stamp within the file name in the format 'Filename_yyyyMMdd_hhmm.bak'.

The script I have created works if I manually enter the time to match the file but when I try and automate it, it wont work because the time can change when the file is generated (generally only by a matter on minutes.

Would someone be able to help on how to rectify this?

```
    DECLARE @BackupFile varchar(1000)

    SELECT @BackupFile = SELECT '\NETWORKLOCATION\FILENAME_' + FORMAT(CAST(GETDATE()  AS date),'yyyyMMdd') + '_HHmm.bak')

    RESTORE DATABASE [Test]
    FROM DISK = @BackupFile
    WITH REPLACE
```

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: You don't need to cast `GETDATE()` to a date. The question is confusing though - you don't specify a *time* so you can't restore from any file that contains a time element. If you don't specify a time, how are you going to identify which file to restore in the day?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, not how you think it can be done. If there are 5 backups in a day, which one do you want to restore? *Restoring* isn't something that should be done blindly either. Are you using backups as a way to replicate databases perhaps? Why not create a script that backs the database into a *specific* file and then restores it from that file to another server?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis - thanks for your replies.  We receive a file from an external company every morning which goes in to a folder with about 4 days worth of files, so I am trying to pull the latest file into a database.  I can get the correct date of the file (because the latest will always be today) but because the time the file was generated is also in the file name and this can vary, I can't seem to get the time into the script.

Comment: Try sp_DatabaseRestore. It lists and parses the file names to find the latest one before trying to restore. I copied the snippet that shows how the file listing is generated in my answer. The *latest* file for a specific database name is the one with the `MAX()` filename

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a go.  I'm very new to all this, so just trying to get my head around it all.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL is very limited when it comes to *file* processing. It's better to use scripts like Ola Hallengren's [Backup script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) and Brent Ozar's [sp_DatabaseRestore](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/databaserestore-open-source-database-restore-stored-procedure/) for complex tasks.

Ola Hallengren's script can backup one or more databases with verification, cleanup etc. The statement :

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

Will find all user databases, create full backups in `c:\Backup` whose names have the format :

```
SERVER_DATABASE_FULL_YYYYMMDD_hhmmss.bak
```

It will also verify the backups and clean older backups

Brent Ozar's script automates restoring backups created using Ola Hallengren's naming conventions.

This call will restore the latest full backup for the database `LogShipMe` :

```
EXEC dbo.sp_DatabaseRestore 
  @Database = 'LogShipMe', 
  @BackupPathFull = 'D:\Backup\SQL2016PROD1A\LogShipMe\FULL\', 
  @BackupPathLog = 'D:\Backup\SQL2016PROD1A\LogShipMe\LOG\', 
  @ContinueLogs = 0, 
  @RunRecovery = 1;
```

If you check the source code for `sp_DatabaseRestore` you'll see that you really don't want to write this yourself. Files are retrieved using :

```
SET @cmd = N'DIR /b "' + @BackupPathFull + N'"';

INSERT INTO @FileList (BackupFile)
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Which puts all files into a table variable so they can be filtered, ordered etc.